# Unable to get product category name, url from product detail view page

Tags: magento-1.7, url, category-products

Its a uncommon issue that i face while getting the product category in product detail page.

My code is working fine in **staging** and not working in **live**.

I used below code to get the **current category**.

```
if (Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
  // Category Name
  $current_category =  Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();
  // Category ID
  $category_id =  Mage::registry('current_category')->getId();
  // Catergory Url
  $url = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($category_id)->getUrl();
}
```

This code is working fine in staging not in live.

I tried this approach also(**Method 2**)

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
          $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
          $categorynm =  $category->getName();
          $url = $category->getUrl();    
    }
```

Using this method also i am unable to get the category url in live.
Please help me to find this issue.its totally uncommon scenario works in staging and not  working in live.

I tried several method from stack exchange questions but i am unable to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at
[how to get category name of current product (on product detail page)
in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053742/how-to-get-category-name-of-current-product-on-product-detail-page-in-magento)

The reason it may work in dev is because you are going directly from a category to a product page. If you visit the product page directly nothing will be display because a product can be attached to multiple categories so magento does not now which category should get display.

The current_category registry is not always set, see

> viewAction() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php
>
> prepareAndRender() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php
>
> initProduct() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product.php Line #321

To get the category id on a product detail page you need to do something like

```
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();

if(count($categoryIds) ){
   $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[0];
   $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);

    echo $_category->getName();
 }
```

Comment: I am using the same file, same coding and the hosts are different.
what can i look with the updated section?

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: no erros, i am just echo the category name in a hidden field.its not view

Comment: Try debugging to make sure the is assigned to a category. Check to see what each of these value return $categoryIds, $firstCategoryId ... etc

Comment: Thank you R.S.the product not assign to any category.